# Bitmap save invalid parameters

Tags: c#, bitmap, save, screenshot

I'm trying to create a Screenshot Tool, just for learning more C#.

If I want to save the Screenshot, I get the Error "invalid parameters." What did I wrong? Here is my method.

```
private void TakeSnapshot()
{
    string myDir = "C:\\Screenshots";

    try
    {
        Bitmap printscreen = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
        Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(printscreen as Image);
        graphics.CopyFromScreen(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height, 0, 0, printscreen.Size);
        printscreen.Dispose();
        printscreen.Save(myDir + "Screenshot.png", ImageFormat.Png);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: What line does the exception happen and what does the documentation say about what parameters are needed? Also you should `Dispose` after `Save`.

Comment: The screenshot wil be saved now, but the new problem is, the whole screenshot is just black / empty.

Comment: Looks like you are missing a "\" in your file path. A good habit to get into is to use `Path.Combine()` to create file system paths because it will add these things for you.

Comment: Ok im done, thank you very much. :)

Answer (score 0):

There are four problems:

- CopyFromScreen has wrong parameters. This is why the result is all black. Please look up in the help the proper parameters:

  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw1kt6f9(v=vs.110).aspx
- You dispose before save. Do it the other way around.
- The path of the image is missing a backslash.
- The graphics object must be disposed as well.

Comment: Use double line breaks to separate your paragraphs. Single line breaks are ignored by the SO text parser. See formatting help or use the UI buttons if you want to show the items as list.

Comment: Oh, and in this case... he should use a `using` block around the bitmap. That'll make it clear it can only be used inside that block.